# If the qty is greater than 0 force to select dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, select, input

I need to validate input type and select box if the input type has value greater than 1 they are force to choose both select unless the input type is 0.

```
<div class="form1">
<input type="number" value="0">
<select>
<option disabled value selected>Please select</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 3</option>
</select>
<select>
<option disabled value selected>Please select</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 3</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form2">
<input type="number" value="0">
<select>
<option disabled value selected>Please select</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 3</option>
</select>
<select>
<option disabled value selected>Please select</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option 1">Option 3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="">
Add To Cart
</button>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2maqkq1h/1/

Comment: `disbaled` top quality spelling :P

Comment: This seems suspiciously like you want us to write your code for you. Why do you specifically mention jQuery? In case you're not aware, Javascript is not the same as jQuery. jQuery is just a convenience library to make Javascript easier (but almost everyone uses it, so it can be confusing to work out what it is).